# asyncFileUpload.UploadedFileError occurs on page partial post back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I hope someone will respond.  I have a control that has an update panel (set to conditional updates) that has an asyncfileupload control in it.  The controls works fine at first, but if I upload a file, then cause its update panel to update, the asyncfileupload.UploadedFileError  will fire without it or asyncFileUpload.UploadedComplete ever being called.  Here is how I create my control:

```
Public Class FileUpload
    Inherits ScriptControl
    Implements INamingContainer, IPostBackEventHandler
    Private WithEvents asyncFileUpload As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload
....

 asyncFileUpload = New AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload
 With asyncFileUpload
    .ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.AutoID
    .UploadingBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(UploadingBackColor)
    .CompleteBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(CompleteBackColor)
    .UploaderStyle = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.UploaderStyleEnum.Traditional
    .ThrobberID = img.UniqueID
 End With
'then the control gets added to a Panel.  
'events:
Protected Sub fileUploadFailure(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles asyncFileUpload.UploadedFileError

'do stuff
end Sub

 Protected Sub SaveUploadedFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles asyncFileUpload.UploadedComplete

'do stuff
End Sub
```

As I mentioned, the control works fine when uploading a file.  But I have a linkbutton in the same control that allows the user to download the uploaded file (causing the control's update panel to update).  When this occurs, the fileUploadFailure event fires for no apparent reason (as no upload has taken place).  Can anyone explain what is happening and how to prevent this?

Comment: What the value of StatusMessage property of AsyncFileUploadEventArgs whrn error occurs?

Comment: "The File Attached Has An Invalid Filenmae".  I believe it has something to do with the fact taht the last uploaded file is never cleared out but I'm not sure how to remedy this.

Comment: and what is `State` property value?

Comment: What do you mean?  The only properties I see for the AsyncFileUploadEventArgs are Status Message, File Name, File Size, and State.  Do you mean State?  That value is "2"

Comment: Yes, the state value = 2

Comment: Try to set `PersistFile` property of AsyncFileUpload control to `True`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried as you suggested but the same error occurs.  I also tried:  asyncFileUpload.ClearAllFilesFromPersistedStore() after the file is initially uploaded but the same error occurs as well.

Comment: After working with this for a while, I realized that this seems to be an issue if the button I use to to start the download is a linkbutton.  If I change this to a Button, it's fine.  Anyone know why this would be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with this for a while, I realized that this seems to be an issue if the button I use to to start the download is a linkbutton. If I change this to a Button, it's fine.